# Y-axis slipping causing failed prints

Tags: marlin, ramps-1.4, y-axis

My Y-axis on my Monoprice maker select running ramps 1.4 and Marlin makes a thud noise when moving every now and then.  I have noticed a 1 to 2 mm shift in the print when this occurs.  I tighten the belts and alas no joy.  I ordered new bearings which should be coming Monday.  I also tried slowing the print down and still get the same result.  Anyone have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the X-axis top smooth rod came out.  this caused the extruder to bang around and shift on the Y-axis when it shifted forward. thank everyone for their help.

Answer (score 3):

A thudding noise is usually a belt slipping through its end-restraints. A clicking noise is usually a stepper motor missing a step. Seized bearings could be the cause.